# Socket in emulator remains open. focus on onResume() method?

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I open a socket inside the doInBackground() method of an object that extends the AsyncTask class. I do close this socket immediately after use. But When i use the back button on the emulator and then launch my app from the menu or when i launch it from eclipse without any changes to the code, I get the BindException(even if i do this after 5 mins giving enough time for TIME_WAIT state or 2MSL wait state).

But if i edit my code in eclipse (say add 2 random chars and remove em and save) and run my app, I don't get this exception. What has to be done in order to accept multiple connections on the same port? I've tried setReuseAddress(true) but that doesn't seem to be working either.

I implement the onResume() method of my activity and simply call super.onResume() in it. Could working on this method lead to a solution, or what exactly has to be done? I'm open to any idea.

Any suggestions?
@Edit:

```
class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 private String fname;
String aa=""; 
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ed.setText(result);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    ServerSocket ss;

    try
        {

        ss = new ServerSocket(8000);
        s=ss.accept();
        s.setReuseAddress(true);
        BufferedReader get = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        aa=get.readLine();
        s.close();


        }
    catch(IOException e)
        {
        //System.out.println(e.toString());
        aa=""+e;

        }
    return aa;
}
```

}

I could see the exception in my TextView saying "BindException: Address already in use" when i run my app again. But clearly i've closed my socket.

Activity code :

```
public class ContactReceiver extends Activity {
 TextView ed;Socket s;
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
super.onCreate(b);
setContentView(R.layout.receiver);
  ed=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   new LongOperation().execute("");

}
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();

}
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
//  new LongOperation().execute("");
}
```

The activity class is not closed. I have my AsyncTask class as a child class inn here

Comment: posting some code and logcat error will help

Comment: When you press the button, Is the Socket still listening or already connected to client?

Comment: @Remdroid :I don't have a button. All i have in my layout is a textView to display either the received message or my exception. And i call ` new LongOperation().execute("");` from onCreate() method. I tried doing this from onResume() method too but...no use. Do u suggest that calling this from a listener of a button would solve ,y problem?

Comment: I mean the back button in emulator :)

Comment: Show also the code of your activity